# How to add one more "done" to related Foursquare tip on own website?

Tags: hyperlink, foursquare

I created Tips in Foursquare.
In my website, I give a link to that tips in the related pages.
When user clicks the link he can see the tip page in Foursquare.

Is it possible to add a button in my website, so when he clicks the button,
that tip will be "done" for that user in Foursquare.
Is it possible with Foursquare API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's only possible if the user has authorized your website/application to make foursquare requests on their behalf. See https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/auth for more details